# Ways to handle dynamic public IP address for AWS EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Recently I have successfully set up a Windows server SFTP server. I noticed that whenever I shut down my EC2 instance and re-run it, the public IP address will change.

This is an issue for me as I key in the public IP address in my hardware settings and I do not wish to update the IP address every time the EC2 instance restart; especially when some of my hardware are miles away from my location!

What kind of approach should I take to tackle this issue? I remember that dynamic DNS will resolve dynamic public IP address, will it work in this case?

Comment: Alternatively: [Amazon Route 53: How to automatically update IP addresses without using Elastic IPs - DEV Community](https://dev.to/aws/amazon-route-53-how-to-automatically-update-ip-addresses-without-using-elastic-ips-h7o)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you need to do is to attach a [Elastic IP Address](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-eips.html) to your instance.

By attaching this to your instance, whenever the instance stops or restarts the public IP address associated with the instance will remain.

> An Elastic IP address is a static, public IPv4 address designed for dynamic cloud computing. You can associate an Elastic IP address with any instance or network interface for any VPC in your account.

Comment: Note: An Elastic IP address will cost `$0.005/hour` when it is attached to a _stopped_ instance. (Max 12c/day, so nothing much to worry about.)